# Counting Items/Rows in DB as Columns Grouped by Another Column

Tags: sql, count, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper, pivot-table

What I want to do is basically:

```
 select Type, (Count(*) where Date='')as 10/1, (Count(*) where Date='')as 10/2
 from my table
 group by Type
```

What I want it to look like is:

```
 Type   10/1    10/2
 1      5       7
 2      3       1
 3      6       9
 4      1       3
 5      9       8
```

However, when I try to run a full select within each count column, I end up getting

```
 Type   10/1    10/2
 1      12      15
 2      12      15
 3      12      15
 4      12      15
 5      12      15
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. I'm not sure if I will need to run a pivot or not, but I wouldn't think so. Additionally after I can run that for any specific day, I was thinking about trying to put the date into a variable and trying to run the whole thing for a date range, generating columns dynamically for each day its run. I would probably create a new question for that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

```
SELECT TYPE
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN MyDate = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [10/1]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN MyDate = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [10/2]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY TYPE
```

Comment: This actually worked. I just had to take the [10/1] and add it to the end "As Oct1"