# Dynamically Creating Column Counts Per Day of Month

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, dynamic-columns

OK, so I have this query to find number of types per day like below. (Courtesy of MarkD here [Counting Items/Rows in DB as Columns Grouped by Another Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21195777/counting-items-rows-in-db-as-columns-grouped-by-another-column))

```
 select type,
           sum(case when MyDate = '' then 1 else 0 end) as "10/1",
           sum(case when MyDate = '' then 1 else 0 end) as "10/2
           ...etc
 from MyTabe
 group by type
```

However, I want to dynamically create date columns and have the count generated for each column, otherwise I would end up manually adding a new column for each day of the month.

Comment: If you dynamically create the columns, then you need to dynamically create sums for the counts.  This could be accomplished using aggregates on the columns and the [group by grouping sets](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets.php) nomenclature.

Comment: I think the  Grouping/Rollup stuff is a little ahead of what I'm trying to do with the day of the month. I think I just need to create a variable or function that will replace the MyDate value for each day of a given month value somewhere. That should work the same as running the sum above manually for each day of Oct for example. I've already written each day inline for october...just wondering if someone had a way to automate the insertion of each day of the month with a single variable/function value or line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best way to get the output I wanted was to do the following:

```
 define startDate = to_date('2013-10-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
 select type,
       sum(case when MyDate = &&startDate then 1 else 0 end) as "1"
       , sum(case when MyDate = &&startDate +1 then 1 else 0 end) as "2"
       , sum(case when MyDate = &&startDate +2 then 1 else 0 end) as "3"
       , sum(case when MyDate = &&startDate +3 then 1 else 0 end) as "4"
       ...etc for as many days of current month I am running
       , sum(case when MyDate = &&startDate +29 then 1 else 0 end) as "30"   
       , sum(case when MyDate = &&startDate +30 then 1 else 0 end) as "31"--This would be commented out for Nov  
 from MyTabe
 group by type
 order by type
 ;
```

This way if I want to run this for Nov, Dec, Jan, and so on, I can just change the variable at the top and run the query. This is what I was looking for; however, I still wonder if it would be possible to generate the columns dynamically, but the more I look at it, the more I think that would require a pivot table.